# Tie melted table object back to original dataframe?

Tags: r, string, lapply

I am trying to count the number of times each word in a row in a dataframe occurs at a given time. Here is my dataframe:

```
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame("Corpus" = c("this is some text", 
                              "here is some more text text",
                              "more food for everyone",
                              "less for no one",
                              "something text here is some more text",
                              "everyone should go home",
                              "more random text",
                              "random text more more more",
                              "plenty of random text",
                              "the final piece of random everyone text"),

                 "Class" = c("X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y",
                           "Y", "Y", "Z",
                           "Z", "Z"),

                 "OpenTime" = c("12/01/2016 10:45:00", "11/07/2016 10:32:00",
                                "11/15/2015 01:45:00", "08/23/2012 1:23:00",
                                "12/17/2016 11:45:00", "12/16/2016 9:47:00",
                                "04/11/2015 04:23:00", "11/27/2016 12:12:00",
                                "08/25/2015 10:46:00", "09/27/2016 10:46:00"))
```

I am trying to get this result:

```
Class    OpenTime             Word    Frequency
X        12/01/2016 10:45:00  this    1
X        12/01/2016 10:45:00  is      1
X        12/01/2016 10:45:00  some    1
X        12/01/2016 10:45:00  text    1
Y        11/07/2016 10:32:00  here    1
Y        11/07/2016 10:32:00  is      1
Y        11/07/2016 10:32:00  some    1
Y        11/07/2016 10:32:00  more    1
Y        11/07/2016 10:32:00  text    2
...
```

I'd love to do this all with `groupby` in `dplyr`, but I haven't yet got that to work. Instead, this is what I've tried:

```
splits <- strsplit(as.character(df$Corpus), split = " ")

counts <- lapply(splits, table)

counts.melted <- lapply(counts, melt)
```

This gives me the transposed view I want:

```
> counts.melted
[[1]]
  Var1 value
1   is     1
2 some     1
3 text     1
4 this     1

[[2]]
  Var1 value
1 here     1
2   is     1
3 more     1
4 some     1
5 text     1
...
```

But how can I tie that list of melted vectors back with the original data to produce the desired output above? I tried using `rep` to repeat the the `Class` value for as many words there were in each row, but have had little success. It would be easy to do all of this in a `for` loop, but I would **much** rather do this using vectorised methods like `lapply`.

```
out.df <- data.frame("RRN" = NULL, "OpenTime" = NULL, 
                 "Word" = NULL, "Frequency" = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those coming here in the future, I was able to vectorize most of the solution to my problem. Unfortunately, I'm still looking for ways to use `lapply` instead of the `for` loop below, but this does exactly what I want:

```
# split each row in the corpus column on spaces
splits <- strsplit(as.character(df$Corpus), split = " ")

# count the number of times each word in a row appears in that row
counts <- lapply(splits, table)

# melt that table to make things more palatable
counts.melted <- lapply(counts, melt)

# the result data frame to which we'll append our results
out.df <- data.frame("Class" = c(), "OpenTime" = c(), 
                     "Word" = c(), "Frequency" = c())

# it would be better to vectorize this, using something like lapply
for(idx in 1:length(counts.melted)){

  # coerce the melted table at that index to a data frame
  count.df <- as.data.frame(counts.melted[idx])

  # change the column names
  names(count.df) <- c("Word", "Frequency")

  # repeat the Classand time for that row to fill in those column
  count.df[, 'Class'] <- rep(as.character(df[idx, "Class"]), nrow(count.df))
  count.df[, 'OpenTime'] <- rep(as.character(df[idx, "OpenTime"]), nrow(count.df))

  # append the results
  out.df <- rbind(out.df, count.df)
}
```